# Incorrect Padding while decrypt using AES python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, aes

So I am implementing AES encryption and decryption algorithm that takes in the password as sha1 hashed value below is the encryption logic

```
def encrypt(password, message):
    # Hash the password using SHA1
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha1(password.encode()).hexdigest()

    # Use the hashed password as the key for AES
    cipher = AES.new(hashed_password[:16].encode(), AES.MODE_CBC)

    # Pad the message to a multiple of the block size
    padded_message = pad(message.encode(), AES.block_size)

    # Encrypt the message
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(padded_message)

    # Encode the ciphertext in base64
    encrypted_text = base64.b64encode(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')
    

    # Return the encrypted message
    return encrypted_text
```

The encrypt method runs successfuly without any errors
Then below is the decrypt method

```
def decrypt(password, encrypted_text):
    # Hash the password using SHA1
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha1(password.encode()).hexdigest()

    # Use the hashed password as the key for AES
    cipher = AES.new(hashed_password[:16].encode(), AES.MODE_CBC)

    # Decode the encrypted text from base64
    ciphertext = base64.b64decode(encrypted_text)

    # Decrypt the message
    padded_message = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)

    # Unpad the message
    message = unpad(padded_message, AES.block_size).decode()

    # Return the decrypted message
    return message
```

Also the necessary imports are below

```
import hashlib
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
import base64
```

Now when I run the following code

```
password = "justKey"
message = "Hello, World!"

encrypted_text = encrypt(password, message)
print(encrypted_text)
decrypted_message = decrypt(password, encrypted_text)


print(decrypted_message)
```

It returns with the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    decrypted_message = decrypt(password, encrypted_text)
  File "main.py", line 40, in decrypt
    message = unpad(padded_message, AES.block_size).decode()
  File "/home/runner/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cryptodome/Util/Padding.py", line 92, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.
```

Is there anything that I am missing, earlier I was using AES without any hashing of the password, but as the new password is not 16 bytes, so using sha1 to generate 16 bytes hash of it. Also I know that the hash generated is different everytime, So can this be a pin point?

Comment: During encryption, a random IV is generated. This must be determined (`cipher.iv`) and used during decryption, which does not happen, s. the [PyCryptodome docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#cbc-mode).

Comment: Note that a fast hash as key derivation is a vulnerability, there are key derivation functions for that. Also for the key not the hex encoding but the raw data should be used.

Comment: so iv needs to be same for encryption as well as decryption? @Topaco

Comment: Yes, the IV from the encryption must be used for decryption. The IV is usually contacted with the ciphertext and both are given to the decrypting side (note that the IV is not secret).